# New column based on the largest value in a group indexed by Group ID

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
Group_ID    probability 
34883       0.002676    
34883       0.17826266  
34883       0.01399753  
34883       0.04569782  
34883       0.02799506  
34883       0.02634829  
34883       0.02923014  
34883       0.13544669  
34883       0.07595718  
34883       0.19246604  
34883       0.20028818  
34883       0           
34883       0           
34883       0.07163442  
34897       0.03329843  
34897       0.07643979  
34897       0.09570681  
34897       0.00376963  
34897       0.01780105  
34897       0.0008377   
34897       0.08125654  
34897       0.10764398  
34897       0.25780105  
34897       0.10910995  
34897       0           
34897       0.02743455  
34897       0.18890052  
34897       0
```

where the probabilities in `probability` sum to 1 for each `Group_ID`. I want to create a new column called `argmax` which indicates the position of the largest probability for each Group_ID and argmax = 1 if the row has the greatest probability for that Group_ID and zero otherwise. Hence the outcome looks like:

```
Group_ID    probability argmax
34883       0.002676    0
34883       0.17826266  0
34883       0.01399753  0
34883       0.04569782  0
34883       0.02799506  0
34883       0.02634829  0
34883       0.02923014  0
34883       0.13544669  0
34883       0.07595718  0
34883       0.19246604  1
34883       0.20028818  0
34883       0           0
34883       0           0
34883       0.07163442  0
34897       0.03329843  0
34897       0.07643979  0
34897       0.09570681  0
34897       0.00376963  0
34897       0.01780105  0
34897       0.0008377   0
34897       0.08125654  0
34897       0.10764398  0
34897       0.25780105  1
34897       0.10910995  0
34897       0           0
34897       0.02743455  0
34897       0.18890052  0
34897       0           0
```

I googled for a bit and I think it might have something to do with idxmax but I am not sure how to proceed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.transform('max')` to get the max value for that group:

```
df.assign(argmax = df['probability'].eq(df.groupby('Group_ID')['probability'].transform('max')).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
    Group_ID  probability  argmax
0      34883     0.002676       0
1      34883     0.178263       0
2      34883     0.013998       0
3      34883     0.045698       0
4      34883     0.027995       0
5      34883     0.026348       0
6      34883     0.029230       0
7      34883     0.135447       0
8      34883     0.075957       0
9      34883     0.192466       0
10     34883     0.200288       1
11     34883     0.000000       0
12     34883     0.000000       0
13     34883     0.071634       0
14     34897     0.033298       0
15     34897     0.076440       0
16     34897     0.095707       0
17     34897     0.003770       0
18     34897     0.017801       0
19     34897     0.000838       0
20     34897     0.081257       0
21     34897     0.107644       0
22     34897     0.257801       1
23     34897     0.109110       0
...
24     34897     0.000000       0
25     34897     0.027435       0
26     34897     0.188901       0
27     34897     0.000000       0
```